# Rails: How can I incrementally add items to a sorted list in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord, acts-as-list

I am trying to create a set list app for musicians. Users can upload their repertoire of songs & pick songs from a list of those songs to populate a set list for a specific performance.

See image: [setlist_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISep8.png).
Clicking the arrow icon on the songs on the *left* should add the song to a sortable list on the *right*.

Models in question:

```
class Setlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  # join between Set Lists & Arrangements(songs)
  has_many :items, -> { order(position: :asc) }
  has_many :arrangements, through: :items
end
```

-

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  # join between Set Lists & Arrangements(songs)
  belongs_to :arrangement
  belongs_to :setlist
  acts_as_list scope: :setlist
end
```

-

```
class Arrangement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :attachments     
  # join between Set Lists & Arrangements(songs)
  has_many :items
  has_many :setlists, through: :items
end
```

Basically a setlist has many arrangements(which are songs) thru items(join table), and arrangements(songs) of course can be on many setlists.

The code I have in the view for the button to add a song is:

```
<%= link_to(organization_setlists_path(:arrangement_id => song.arrangements.first.id, setlist_id: @new_set.id, remote: true), method: "post", class: "secondary-content" )
```

which is a post request (including params for the song's arrangement id & id of a Setlist.new made in the new action) to the create action of the setlists controller, as below:

```
class SetlistsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    if @new_set.nil?
        @new_set = Setlist.create
        @new_item = Item.new 
    end
end

def create
    @arrangement = Arrangement.find(params[:arrangement_id])
    @new_item = Item.new 
    @new_item.setlist_id = Setlist.find(params[:setlist_id])
    @new_item.arrangement_id = @arrangement.id
    if @new_item.save
        flash[:message] = "Song Sucessfully Added!"
    else
        flash[:message] = "Something Went Wrong"
    end
end
```

Ideally, I would like a new item to be created(remotely) for the same setlist after each click of the add/arrow button, until the user is done creating that setlist. To display that on the right side, I have:

```
<% if @new_set && @new_set.items.count >=1 %>
    <ul>
    <% @new_set.items.each do |item| %>
        <li class="center-align"><%= item.arrangement.title %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% else %>
    <p class="center-align">Add Songs From The List On The Left</p>
<% end %>
```

Eventually, the user should be able to finalize it and move on to creating another set list if they want.

I really have no idea how to go about this other than what I have done here, which is not working. The issues are:

For one, the create action is actually creating an item & assigning the new item the foreign key for arrangements but not for the setlists for some reason, even tho the setlist id is being passed in correctly from the link_to params.

Also, each time the page is refreshed, a new set list is generated from what I have in the new action, so each item added will go into a setlist, then a blank set list is generated, so nothing will ever appear on the right.

And finally, this just seems messy all together. Anyone have a better design strategy to accomplish this? Any help would be severely appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that your controller violates conventions.

Your `SetlistController` should create a `Setlist` when the user POSTs to `/setlists`.

If you want to create a new child record you would POST to `/setlists/:setlist_id/items`. This would be handled by `ItemsController`.

```
# routes.rb
resources :setlists, shallow: true do
  resources :items
end
```

---

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html
  before_action :find_setlist!, only: [:create, :index]

  def create
    @item = @setlist.items.build(item_params)
    @item.save
    respond_with @item
  end

  # ...

  private
    def find_setlist!
      @setlist = Setlist.includes(:items).find!(params[:setlist_id])
    end

    def items_params
       params.require(:item)
             .permit(
                :arrangement_id
             )
    end
end
```

---

```
<% @arrangements.each do |a| %>
  <%= button_to 'Add to set', setlist_items_path(@setlist), 
      arrangement_id: a.id, remote: true 
  %>
<% end %>
```

**An alternative** is to use [`accepts_nested_attibutes_for :items`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to allow the `Setlist` to accept the parameters for the items as well.

The key difference here is when adding additional items to an existing setlist it would for example use:

```
PATCH /setlist/:id
params: {
  item_attributes: [
    {
      arrangement_id: 2
    },
    {
      arrangement_id: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

The real benefit is that the user can have performed multiple operations such as adding/removing and you just need to push the single setlist to the database to update the state, instead of using multiple POST / DELETE calls for each child record.

```
class Setlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  # join between Set Lists & Arrangements(songs)
  has_many :items, -> { order(position: :asc) }
  has_many :arrangements, through: :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true
end
```

---

```
class SetlistsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html
  before_action :set_setlist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @setlist = Setlist.new
    @setlist.items.build 
  end

  def create
    @setlist = Setlist.new(setlist_params)
    @setlist.save
    respond_with @setlist
  end

  def update
    @setlist.update(setlist_params)
    @setlist.items.build
    respond_with @setlist
  end

  # ...

  private
    def set_setlist
      @setlist = Setlist.includes(:items).find(params[:id])
    end

    def setlist_params
      params.require(:setlist)
            .permit(
              :foo, :bar # attributes for the list
              items_attributes: [ :position, :arrangement_id, :_destroy ]
            )
    end
end
```

---

The basic form setup to support this would look something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@setlist) do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for :items do |item| %>
    <%= item.number_field :postition %>
    <%= item.collection_select(:arrangement_id, @setlist.organization.arrangements, :id, :name) %>
    <%= item.checkbox :_destroy, label: 'Delete?' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Of course this just a plain old synchronous HTML form - adding AJAX functionality and drag'n'drop re-ordering etc is a bit out of scope.

Note that these solutions are not exclusive. You could easily have both options (nested attributes and a designated controller) in your application depending on if your requirements need you to be able to manipulate the child records individually as well or if you want to provide it as part of your API.

Comment: You may want to search github for a few different `Todo` apps and study how they approached the problem. It's a very similar scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much!! The misuse of the setlists controller was pointed out to me not too long after I posted this, and your answer fleshes out even more what needs to be done. I guess I'm so used to creating & "building" objects within the new action and saving them in create, whereas this situation calls for me to do the actual "building" in the edit action, to have a setlist id in params to reference when adding the dependent objects. if I am understanding correctly, in the second solution, the form would be in the edit view, right? This form would produce a drop down box?

Comment: If so, how would I use that solution (using a form) with a simple button click, rather than a drop down menu?

Comment: Since the form with nested attributes is more complex you can't really just use 'button_for'. I would use that instead if you for example want users to have a edit view where they see the entire list and can add and remove